# How do I write and read .pem certs from SPIFFS?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to construct a program for an ESP32 Dev Board that writes my AWS cert files [(https://medium.com/@flynam/securing-your-iot-device-using-ssl-4643110ab901)][1] to SPIFFS so that I can later read them from another program that's loaded via an OTA (over the air) updater.

However, it looks like something is being lost during the read & write process.  The certs will work if hardcoded, but error out when loaded from SPIFFS.

Hardcoding to a variable like the one in `Secrets.h` works:

`static const char AWS_CERT_CA[] PROGMEM`

But when writing that to a file and printing via `Serial.println` I'm missing things like `R"EOF(` and `)EOF"` which I'm assuming are hidden characters.

Does this have to do with writing as a .txt file or perhaps storing in the wrong kind of variable?

The code below is missing some functions, but the relevant portions are below.

I should also mention I am very much a C++ beginner so there's probably some things off with my code above and beyond my initial question.

**main.ino**

```
// ...
#include "Secrets.h" // contains cert files info
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "Esp.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"
// ...


// Where I'm wanting to store my cert files
static char AWS_CERT_CA_FILEPATH[] = "/AWS_CERT_CA.txt";
static char AWS_CERT_CRT_FILEPATH[] = "/AWS_CERT_CRT.txt";
static char AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_FILEPATH[] = "/AWS_CERT_PRIVATE.txt";

// Save a file to the designated location
void saveFile(const char* filePath, const char* contents){
  if(!SPIFFS.exists(filePath)) {
      File writeLog = SPIFFS.open(filePath, FILE_WRITE);
      if(!writeLog) {
          Serial.print("Couldn't open ");
          Serial.println(filePath); 
      } else {
        writeLog.print(contents);
        delay(50);
        Serial.print(contents);
        Serial.print(" written to file system");
        Serial.println(filePath);
        delay(50);
        writeLog.close();
      }
      delay(50);

  } else {
    Serial.print(filePath);
    Serial.print(" already exists.  Call remove() first.");
  }
}

// Remove files if they are there already, then save anew
void saveCerts(){

  SPIFFS.remove(AWS_CERT_CA_FILEPATH);
  SPIFFS.remove(AWS_CERT_CRT_FILEPATH);
  SPIFFS.remove(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_FILEPATH);

  saveFile(AWS_CERT_CA_FILEPATH, AWS_CERT_CA);
  saveFile(AWS_CERT_CRT_FILEPATH, AWS_CERT_CRT);
  saveFile(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_FILEPATH, AWS_CERT_PRIVATE);
}

// Load the file into char* ... 
// Loads, but perhaps not into the correct format?
bool loadFile(const char* filePath, char* buffer){
    File f = SPIFFS.open(filePath, "r");
    if (f && f.size()) {

      Serial.print("Reading ");
      Serial.print(f.size());
      Serial.print(" bytes from file ");
      Serial.println(filePath);

      int pos = 0;
      while (f.available()) {
        buffer[pos] = f.read();
        pos++;
      }

      buffer[pos] = 0;

      f.close();
      return true;

    } else {
      Serial.print("No contents available for ");
      Serial.println(filePath);
      return false;
    }
}

// Allows for creation of correctly size char arrays
int getFileSize(const char* filePath){
    File f = SPIFFS.open(filePath, "r");
    if (f && f.size()) {
      return (int)f.size();

    } else {
      return 0;
    }
}

void connectAWS()
{
  // Need to save these to file
  char AWS_CERT_CA_LOADED[getFileSize(AWS_CERT_CA_FILEPATH)];
  char AWS_CERT_CRT_LOADED[getFileSize(AWS_CERT_CRT_FILEPATH)];
  char AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_LOADED[getFileSize(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_FILEPATH)];

  loadFile(AWS_CERT_CA_FILEPATH, AWS_CERT_CA_LOADED);
  loadFile(AWS_CERT_CRT_FILEPATH, AWS_CERT_CRT_LOADED);
  loadFile(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_FILEPATH, AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_LOADED);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  // From here on out is code from tutorials and works when 
  // certs are hardcoded

  Serial.println("Connecting to Wi-Fi");

  // TODO Put in some code when auth fails
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Configure WiFiClientSecure to use the AWS IoT device credentials
  net.setCACert(AWS_CERT_CA_LOADED);
  net.setCertificate(AWS_CERT_CRT_LOADED);
  net.setPrivateKey(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE_LOADED);

  // Connect to the MQTT broker on the AWS endpoint we defined earlier
  client.begin(AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT, 8883, net);

  // Create a message handler
  client.onMessage(messageHandler);

  Serial.print("Connecting to AWS IOT");

  while (!client.connect(THINGNAME)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }

  if(!client.connected()){
    Serial.println("AWS IoT Timeout!");
    return;
  }

  // Subscribe to a topic
  client.subscribe(AWS_IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);

  Serial.println("AWS IoT Connected!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPIFFS.begin();
  saveCerts();
  connectAWS();
  publishMessage();
}
```

**In secrets.h**

```
#include <pgmspace.h>

#define SECRET

// Amazon Root CA 1
static const char AWS_CERT_CA[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
awholebunchofrandomlettersandnumbers
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

// Device Certificate
static const char AWS_CERT_CRT[] PROGMEM = R"KEY(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
awholebunchofrandomlettersandnumbers
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

)KEY";

// Device Private Key
static const char AWS_CERT_PRIVATE[] PROGMEM = R"KEY(
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
awholebunchofrandomlettersandnumbers
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
)KEY";
```

**Print and Error Message**

```
[E][vfs_api.cpp:135] remove(): /AWS_CERT_CRT.txt does not exists or is directory
[E][vfs_api.cpp:135] remove(): /AWS_CERT_PRIVATE.txt does not exists or is directory

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
someprivatestuffIerased
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 written to file system/AWS_CERT_CA.txt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
someprivatestuffIerased
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 written to file system/AWS_CERT_CRT.txt

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
someprivatestuffIerased
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 written to file system/AWS_CERT_PRIVATE.txt
Reading 1189 bytes from file /AWS_CERT_CA.txt
Reading 1221 bytes from file /AWS_CERT_CRT.txt
Reading 1676 bytes from file /AWS_CERT_PRIVATE.txt
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 0 - WIFI_READY
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 2 - STA_START
Connecting to Wi-Fi
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 4 - STA_CONNECTED
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 7 - STA_GOT_IP
[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:381] _eventCallback(): STA IP: 192.168.1.192, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.1.1
.Connecting to AWS IOT[V][ssl_client.cpp:56] start_ssl_client(): Free internal heap before TLS 258252
[V][ssl_client.cpp:58] start_ssl_client(): Starting socket
[V][ssl_client.cpp:93] start_ssl_client(): Seeding the random number generator
[V][ssl_client.cpp:102] start_ssl_client(): Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
[V][ssl_client.cpp:115] start_ssl_client(): Loading CA cert
[V][ssl_client.cpp:163] start_ssl_client(): Loading CRT cert
[V][ssl_client.cpp:170] start_ssl_client(): Loading private key
[V][ssl_client.cpp:180] start_ssl_client(): Setting hostname for TLS session...
[V][ssl_client.cpp:195] start_ssl_client(): Performing the SSL/TLS handshake...
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (loopTask) 
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008c363  PS      : 0x00060036  A0      : 0x8008c458  A1      : 0x3ffb0060  
A2      : 0x3ffd9cbc  A3      : 0xbaad5678  A4      : 0x3ffd9cb0  A5      : 0x3ffb0190  
A6      : 0x00000001  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x3ffd9cc8  A9      : 0x3ffd9cb4  
A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x3ffd9cb0  A12     : 0x00005640  A13     : 0x00005568  
A14     : 0x3ffd9da8  A15     : 0x3ffd9ccc  SAR     : 0x0000001f  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4000c2e0  LEND    : 0x4000c2f6  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  

Backtrace: 0x4008c363:0x3ffb0060 0x4008c455:0x3ffb0090 0x40084e00:0x3ffb00b0 0x400850a3:0x3ffb00d0 0x400845c8:0x3ffb00f0 0x400f1099:0x3ffb0110 0x400ee30a:0x3ffb0130 0x400eed36:0x3ffb0150 0x400eeda1:0x3ffb0190 0x400ef154:0x3ffb01c0 0x400ef2ff:0x3ffb0240 0x400ef577:0x3⸮
```

**Update**

Exception can be fixed by making the variables global, but I now receive a repeating invalid certificate format error.

```
[ssl_client.cpp:56] start_ssl_client(): Free internal heap before TLS 256736
[V][ssl_client.cpp:58] start_ssl_client(): Starting socket
[V][ssl_client.cpp:93] start_ssl_client(): Seeding the random number generator
[V][ssl_client.cpp:102] start_ssl_client(): Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
[V][ssl_client.cpp:115] start_ssl_client(): Loading CA cert
[E][ssl_client.cpp:33] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():122]: (-8576) X509 - The CRT/CRL/CSR format is invalid, e.g. different type expected
[E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:132] connect(): start_ssl_client: -8576
[V][ssl_client.cpp:248] stop_ssl_socket(): Cleaning SSL connection.
[V][ssl_client.cpp:56] start_ssl_client(): Free internal heap before TLS 256124
[V][ssl_client.cpp:58] start_ssl_client(): Starting socket
[V][ssl_client.cpp:93] start_ssl_client(): Seeding the random number generator
[V][ssl_client.cpp:102] start_ssl_client(): Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
[V][ssl_client.cpp:115] start_ssl_client(): Loading CA cert
[E][ssl_client.cpp:33] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():122]: (-8576) X509 - The CRT/CRL/CSR format is invalid, e.g. different type expected
```

**Update 2**

Added the following

```
// At top of file
#define FORMAT_SPIFFS_IF_FAILED true

// In setup()
if(!SPIFFS.begin(FORMAT_SPIFFS_IF_FAILED)){
   Serial.println("SPIFFS Mount Failed");
   return;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack decode via https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder? It could also be that since you now allocate the buffers for the certificates on the stack of the function, that there's a stack overflow. Given that the error is `Stack canary watchpoint triggered` this is the most likely cause (a canary is a special value written into the end of the stack to check if it's been overwritten / overflowed). Please try: declare `char AWS_CERT_CA_LOADED[]` and friends variables as **global variables** (outside func) with some constant max memory size (2k), then load certs as usual

Comment: and retry the handshake.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks Maximilian.  That fixed the stack overflow error.  Now I receive an invalid format.  I'll continue to try additional approaches.

Comment: invalid format error is thrown by which function exactly? The certificate loading functions? Have you verified their content to be the same as when using static certificates?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt It seems I needed to format (?) SPIFFS for it to work properly.  Added a bit of code to "Update 2".